# compareTo() getting true or false output

Tags: java

So if I had two strings I understand that if the first string was, let's say, `ape` and the second was `zebra` and I said `word1.compareTo(word2);` the output should be negative.

How would I get an output of `true` or `false`?

Comment: You would not. How does `true` or `false` become an _ordering_?

Comment: i guess you mean `word1.equals(word2)`.

Comment: You should say what a result of true (or false) would indicate.

Answer (score 1):

compareTo() returns a number that is less than, equal to, or greater than zero, corresponding to the first string being before, the same as, or after the second string respectively; so you can test for a particular ordering by comparing the result to 0 with any of the relational operators (`==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`).

For instance:

```
// Returns true only when word1 and word2 are in order or the same
return word1.compareTo(word2) <= 0;
```

and

```
// Do s1 and s2 need to be swapped?
boolean outOfOrder = s1.compareTo(s2) > 0;

if (outOfOrder) {
    // swap s1 and s2
    // ...
}
```

(Note that comparisons give you boolean values that you can return, assign to variables, and so on; you don't need `if (cond) { return true; } else { return false; }`.)

Answer (score 0):

Ternary:

```
(word1.compareTo(word2) == 0) true ? false
```

If/else:

```
if(word1.compareTo(word2) == 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

there are lots of ways to do it. you can make a new method to do it for you if you like.

Comment: what about String s1, s2; if (s1.compareTo(s2) < 0) S.o.p("s1 < s2");

Comment: so could I implement an if else?

Comment: That will print the result, when you do a lexigraphical comparison you have three possible outputs, -1, 0 and 1, so going to true false means you have to specify when you want it true and when you want it false, I just assumed you meant same string = true, otherwise false.

what exactly is it you want to check for?

Comment: I want to check for is one is greater then the other if it is its true if not false

Comment: OK then in that case instead of using == 0 in the ternary/if you use > 0, so (word1.compareTo(word2) > 0) ? true:false